# Thread ID inside a process

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a running process in which I have to create a thread inside the process using pthread:

sample --

```
Process is Running having some PID
I have created a thread using "pthread_create"
```

1. Now I have a process and a thread running inside that process.
2. Then I am killing that process PID using 
   kill -9 PID command

My Question is:

1. By killing parent process does my thread also gets killed and if yes then how the clean up will be done?
2. Can I create a Named Thread using "pthread_create"?
3. How will I verify the thread which I have created is running in side process. (May be using parent PID or process name on linux shell)
4. And last one how to synchronise my new thread with my process 
   example I know  pthread_join,detach and other pthread API so in my case which all I need to use.

Comment: This question is four questions. This is not a Good Thing <tm>.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `pthread_create()`, you don't have a process and a thread but a process and two threads. Concerning your questions:

1. The threads are part of the process. When the last thread exits, the process exits, too, because one doesn't make sense without the other.
2. RTFM.
3. Normally, you check the returnvalue of functions to determine success or failure. What else do you want to verify here? How would you tell the difference?
4. Please read a tutorial or a book on pthreads or POSIX threads. You are asking about which functions to use for synchronization, but you seem to have no idea what that even means.

Comment: How to succeful confuse a newbie: "*... but a process and two threads.*" ;-)

Comment: Yes, I hope this confuses. I hope that this confusion will then eventually break a misconception about what a thread is, leading to an in-depth understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For question 3：Maybe you could use `pstree`

Comment: ... and for completeness: `top` would help as well.